# Using input parameters of defined function inside apply function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Maybe a very naive question, but I am stuck in this: pandas.DataFrame.apply has a possibility to put inside a function.

```
# define function for further usage    
def get_string(df):
        string_input = []
        for id, field in enumerate(df.index):
            string_input.append('<field id="{0}" column="{1}">{2}</field>'.format(id, field, df[field]))
        return '\n'.join(string_input)
```

If i apply it on df i get **perfectly formatted** string file output as wanted

```
global_1 = '\n'.join(df.apply(get_string, axis=1))

output:
<field id="0" column="xxx">49998.0</field>
<field id="1" column="xxx">37492.0</field>
<field id="2" column="xxx">12029.0</field>
```

But why don't i have to put inside **get_string()** necessary input global parameter df **get_string(df)** like this:

```
global_1 = '\n'.join(df.apply(get_string(df), axis=1))
```

and what if i have **more input global parameters**?
I have Googled for it a while, but I am not very clear about it. Could anyone give me some illustrative explanation how it works?
Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: There's really no need to use apply here. Provide a [mcve] with sample data and your expected output and you'll get a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing between `df` the global variable and `df` the local variable.

The `get_string` function defines input variable called `df` and this will overshadow any variable of the same name from higher scopes. The `df` that `get_string` knows is the dataframe you called `apply` upon, not the global `df`. You can try it with different dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum']})
x = pd.DataFrame({'b': ['Hello', 'World']})
y = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['Goodbye', 'World']})

global_1 = '\n'.join(df.apply(get_string, axis=1))
global_2 = '\n'.join(x.apply(get_string, axis=1))
global_3 = '\n'.join(y.apply(get_string, axis=1))

print(global_1)
print(global_2)
print(global_3)
```

Result:

```
# From the global `df`
<field id="0" column="a">Lorem</field>
<field id="0" column="a">Ipsum</field>
# From x
<field id="0" column="b">Hello</field>
<field id="0" column="b">World</field>
# From y
<field id="0" column="c">Goodbye</field>
<field id="0" column="c">World</field>
```

Comment: Thank you for great explanation, but problem comes, when my defined function get_string() requires more than only df like get_string(df, some_list,..), how to put this inside apply function, when it is called only on df? Thank you

Comment: You pass them by keyword in the `apply` call: `df.apply(get_string, axis=1, some_list=..., another_param=...)`